# How can I capture an image without it being cropped to square?

Tags: cordova, ngcordova

I have the camera in my code, but every time after I took the picture, I can only select a portion of picture in square shape. How do I use the full image without crop into a square shape. Here is my code

```
 function takePhoto() {

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        var options = {
          quality: 50,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          allowEdit: true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 300,
          targetHeight: 500,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
          correctOrientation: true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
          vm.receipt = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function (err) {
          UtilTool.showError(err);
        });

      }, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `allowEdit: true,`, that param is the one that takes you to the crop screen, use `allowEdit: false,` or remove the whole line as it's false by default

Comment: On changing allow image to false, it no doubt doesn't ask for crop but the resulting photo displays as left align, it only happens by capturing portrait image.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "photo displays as left align", but if the photo doesn't have the right orientation you can try with this option `correctOrientation: true`. EDIT: nevermind, I've just read your answer where you say the same

Comment: :) yup I was facing the above issue, then did search at my end and posted the information below that i came to know

Answer (score 0):

Removing `allowEdit:true` from options object will disable image editing step i.e. image cropping. 
But in most of the android mobiles, image often rotates to 90 degree in this case. `correctOrientation:true` in option object will fix this rotation issue by displaying the orientation based on device type.